# Объясните предложение (для иностранца)!

Tags: значение-слов, смысл

Перескажите, пожалуйста, простыми словами это предложение:

*Соблюдаете ли Вы без особых затруднений обязательные в вашей среде правила поведения?*

Answer (score 5):

В этом вопросе неудачен порядок слов и их связи (он напоминает исторический казус "сохранить как обновленный"). Сами по себе слова просты: мы знаем, что в вашей среде есть правила поведения, которые нужно обязательно соблюдать. Собственнно вопрос: есть ли у вас затруднения с соблюдением этих правил? В одно предолжение можно уместить всё так:

> Возникают ли у вас [особые, какие-либо] затруднения с соблюдением правил, обязательных в
>   вашей среде?

Answer (score 0):

Простыми словами так: "вам сложно соблюдать обязательные для вас правила?" 
  http://russian.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Фраза вполне грамотна, ничего там не нарушено.

Простыми словами.

Легко ли вам соблюдать этикет вашего круга общения? 
Не трудно ли вам соблюдать принятые правила поведения?

Answer (score 0):

Фраза неудачная. Наиболее точный ее аналог:

**Можете ли Вы сказать, что без особых затруднений соблюдаете обязательные в вашей среде правила поведения?**

А если минимизировать изменения, то так:

**Удается ли Вам без особых затруднений соблюдать обязательные в вашей среде правила поведения?**